# How can I add an email to an existing calendar entry using exchangelib?

Tags: python, outlook, exchangelib

I have an existing calendar event already scheduled.

I am trying to add a number of emails to that existing event, but when I run this function it adds a new event.

I need to be able to: find the event, add the specified email to the event, have the email added get the invitation.

(I'm new to python so try not to judge harshly)

```
def updateInvite(pEmail,pSubj,iY, iM, iD, iHH, iMM):
    pytz_tz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
    tz = EWSTimeZone.localzone()    

    items = account.calendar.view(    
        start=tz.localize(EWSDateTime(iY, iM, iD, iHH, iMM)),        
        end=tz.localize(EWSDateTime(iY, iM, iD, iHH + 2, iMM)),        
        )`   
    for item in items:    
        sEventSubj = item.subject        
        item.save(update_fields=['required_attendees'])
```

**Is called with**

```
pEmail = 'name.last@company.com'
sSubj  = 'Invite Test Meeting with Teams link'
iY = 2020
iD = 29
iM = 4
iHH = 16
iMM = 30
updateInvite(pEmail, sSubj, iY, iM, iD, iHH, iMM)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, use an item attachment. Find the message you would like to attach to your calendar item and create an item attachment for it:

```py
from exchangelib import ItemAttachment

# Create some filter to get the emails you want to attach
messages = account.inbox.all()[:5]
# Create a filter go get your calendar item
item = account.calendar.get(subject='Hello Python')
for message in messages:
    # Create the attachment and give it a name
    attachment = ItemAttachment(name='msg %s' % msg.id[:8], item=message)
    item.attach(attachment)
```